# How to download a string

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a string variable that needs to be downloaded as a file in javascript. I have tried other examples on stackoverflow but they just display the results in the browser instead of downloading it as a file. The string is about 25,000 characters and needs to work in IE 9 and above.

Here is the code I have so far. It does not work in IE as it gives a page cannot be displayed error. In chrome it just displays the result in the browser.

html:

```
<a id="downloadDataButton" href="#" class="btn pull-right">
    <i class="icon-plus"></i> Download
</a>
```

Code:

```
$('#downloadDataButton').on('click', onDownloadData);
function onDownloadData() {
     $(this).attr('href', 'data:text/octet-stream;base64,SGVsbG8gV29ybGQh');
}
```

Comment: Why Javascript? This is normally a server-side issue (where you have full control over the returned data and content type).

Comment: I have inherited some code where a grid is build on the client side. The grid is build using a json filtered object and I thought it might waay easier creating the csv file from this json object.

Comment: In IE 8 and 9, data URIs can only be used for images, but not for navigation or JavaScript generated file downloads

Comment: try changing the MIME type for chrome to display file save dialog

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/UselessCode/qm5AG/ I do not know if it works on IE9 and above

Answer (score -2):

I'm assuming here that you are using an apache server? Open up your `.htaccess` file and put this in.

```
<FilesMatch "\.(?i:txt)$">
  Header set Content-Disposition attachment
</FilesMatch>
```

This should force all txt files to prompt a download instead of being interpreted by the browser. Simply use a pipe to add more files eg `txt|doc|mp3|whatever`